# Help with sobject clone() method

Tags: apex, code-coverage, clone

I am trying to implement the sboject clone() method in my test code and cannot get it to work properly. The code test if a service class performs as expected (record can not be edited if status is == 'Submitted') Here is my code:

```
List<Worklog__c> oldWorklogs = [SELECT Id, Description_Of_Work__c, Worklog_Status__c FROM Worklog__c WHERE Worklog_Status__c = 'Submitted' LIMIT 1];
        Map<Id, Worklog__c> newWorklogs = new Map<Id, Worklog__c>();
        for(Worklog__c wl : oldWorklogs) {
            newWorklogs.get(wl.Id).put(wl.clone(true,true,true,true));
        }

        List<Worklog__c> worklogsWithErrors = WorklogStatusValidationService.protectEditedWorklogSubmissions(oldWorklogs, newWorklogs);
        System.assertEquals(1, worklogsWithErrors.size(), 'Number of errored logs expected: 1 Logs found: ' + worklogsWithErrors.size());
```

Comment: What does protectEditedWorklogSubmissions do?

Comment: If old record field value  == 'Submitted'
&& updated record field value == 'Submitted' throw an error on submission. A record with the status value of 'Submitted' cannot be edited.

Comment: Hi Sam, I've linked what I think is relevant for you. Unit tests can't normally see production data. Make sure you're creating records in your unit test directly. See also [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm).

Comment: If this doesn't help, please let us know, we'll be happy to reopen your question for you. You may want to [edit] your question to include more information that distinguishes your question from the linked one.